# How to iterate through a website that shows no index in the URL

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, data-science

I'm trying to get data from "https://chainplay.gg/" but I'm stuck and I can't get data other than that on page one.
This is the code I wrote and it returns the .csv I'm looking for but, without getting me the other 44 pages of data I can't do much with it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
import json
import csv

r = requests.get('https://chainplay.gg/') 

soup = bs(r.content)

#print(soup.prettify()) 

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', id="__NEXT_DATA__", type="application/json").text) 
#print(data)
data = data["props"]["pageProps"]["game"]
#print(data)

json_object = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
 
with open("games.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_object)

with open('games.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
 
games = data['games']
 
data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w')
 
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

count = 0
 
for game in games:
    if count == 0:
 
        # Writing headers of CSV file
        header = game.keys()
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1
 
    # Writing data of CSV file
    csv_writer.writerow(game.values())

data_file.close()
```

The one above is only the code that I know for sure is working, every other attempt resulted in empty dataframes/continuous error generation.
I tried using Selenium and looking or looking for pages indexes but to no avail. Is there someone that could please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the network traffic when you access the site you can extract the POST requests and find the `pageNumber` parameter that you can use to iterate over the pages.

Try this:

```
import requests

json_data = {
    'pageNumber': 1, # <- change this to retrieve other pages
    'pageSize': 50,
}

response = requests.post('https://api.chainplay.gg/api/app/project/get-games', 
                         json=json_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()["payload"]["games"])
df.head()
```

Output

```
code    name    rank    imageUrl    symbol  blockChains genres  platforms   price   price24hChangePercent   priceChangePercentage7dInCurrency   priceChangePercentage1hInCurrency   volume24h   marketCap   sparkLine7dUrl  dateAdded   sparkLine7d isWatched   isInMainWatchList   mainWatchListId
0   the-sandbox The Sandbox 1   https://tk-storage.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws...   sand    [{'name': 'Ethereum', 'code': 'ethereum', 'ext...   [{'name': 'Metaverse', 'code': 'metaverse'}]    [{'name': 'Windows', 'code': 'windows'}]    0.381557    0.51693 -33.477796  -0.601724   176221778   706710369   https://tk-storage.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws...   2021-11-01T07:43:44Z    None    False   False   None
1   decentraland    Decentraland    2   https://tk-storage.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws...   mana    [{'name': 'Ethereum', 'code': 'ethereum', 'ext...   [{'name': 'Metaverse', 'code': 'metaverse'}]    [{'name': 'Browser', 'code': 'browser'}]    0.341267    1.70391 -30.828218  -0.409165   79353426    621542744   https://tk-storage.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws...   2021-11-01T07:43:44Z    None    False   False   None
2   axie-infinity   Axie Infinity
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea how long I've been trying to get this data!

Comment: Glad that this helped. Good luck with your project!

Comment: May I ask you if there's a good source of information where I newbie like me can learn more about these things?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know a source of information that specifically addresses this. I'd recommend that you look a little more into the developer tools in Chrome or Firefox. As you might know these allow you to easily inspect network traffic that a website invokes. E.g. try right-click a website in your browser and click `Inspect`. Switch to the network tab, reload the page, look for GET or POST requests, especially ones that are visible in the `XHR` sub tab. Copy the request(s) as curl and use a tool like [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com) to convert this to Python.